# Writing after specific row of a tableaux

Tags: youngtab

Suppose we draw a Young diagram and want to write (to specify something) after the diagram; the text will appear after the first row:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{ytableau}
\, & \, & \, & \cr 
\, & *(gray) $y$ & \, \cr 
\, & \, & \,\cr
\,\cr
\end{ytableau} $\leftarrow x$ 
\end{center}
```

This results in the following output:

[image]

But If I want to put the $x$ and the arrow after second row, what is the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a systematic way, but for a few labels it can work.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ytableau}

\newcommand{\labelrow}[2]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{#1}#2}}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{ytableau}
{} & {} & {} & \\
{} & *(gray) y & \labelrow{1em}{$\leftarrow x$} \\
{} & {} & {} \\
{}\\
\end{ytableau}
\]

\end{document}
```

*Caveat.* The added label has zero width; the first argument to `\labelrow` is the offset, which needs to be adjusted by hand.

[image]